# How do I set different colors for different kind of 'comments' in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

[image]

Hi, I have these settings for comments in Visual Studio 2017:

1) two comment bars '//' (dark green in the image) to indicate 'normal comments'.

2) three comment bars '///' (light green) for special notes and titles.

I find this technique very useful to mantain a clearer code, and I would like to apply the same logic (having similar color settings) in Visual Studio Code.

But I can't figure it out how to do it.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!! This should be marked as the correct answer. Thank you very much @Alex!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the comment color by going to: 
**Tools | Options | Environment | Fonts and Colors | Comment**

Answer (score 1):

No. You got it wrong. Tripple slash comment is for documentation generation. It is NOT meant for coloring. When it is used with the proper tags, the compiler autogenerates the relative documentation/tooltips:

```
<summary>Open the connection.</summary>
public void Open()
{
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Later, when one is accessing the `Open()` method in Visual Studio, in addition to the intellisense, a tooltip is shown, with the text "Opens the connection."

AFAIK, there is no such thing as a "coloring of a comment". Nor there are "different comments". What do you mean by that?

If you're looking for a way to order your commenes, you might find useful, to structurize them by using a "comment token", thus making the comment appear on the Visual Studio's Task List. Also, you can create your own tokens. From the menu, open the Tools -> Options dialog; choose Environment => Task List from the list on the left.

So somewhere in you code you might do this:

```
// TODO: Either delete or uncomment the next line.
// settings.decorared = false
```

Then you'll see the TODO note in your Task List, but not the `//settings.decorated`.

Hint: To display the Task List press **Ctrl+\,T**.

Comment: There _are_ different types of comments in C++, and C#. `//` is for a single-line comment, one that continues only until the newline. `/*` and `*/` are for block or multi-line comments that are bracketed by these character pairs and may span any number of lines. Visual Studio, however, does not distinguish between the two types, so coloring them differently is not possible.